# Is such an ellipsis acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, ellipses

If we have the sentence

> She is interested in philosophy (especially philosophy of mathematics).

is the following ellipsis acceptable in modern (American) English?

> She is interested in philosophy (especially of mathematics).

I am asking because I'm weirded out by the fact that to my nonnative ear the second sentence is  right between sounding completely fine and sounding a tiny bit odd.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117795/discussion-on-question-by-aleksandr-is-such-an-ellipsis-acceptable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a native speaker and I think this is perfectly acceptable and understandable. It might not be appropriate in really formal settings but the ellipsis is pretty clear, and the meaning is plainly conveyed. I'd recommend using a comma rather than brackets though:

> She is interested in philosophy, especially of mathematics.